# Having trouble passing data through Lists

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**What i wanted to do**

> I have a class (BlackBoard) that holdes data. and class NPC Gets the data from (BlackBoard). (NPC_Guard) inherits from (NPC) which uses (NPC_Movement) to move by using the data from (BlackBoard).

**BlackBoard class**

```
public sealed class BlackBoard : MonoBehaviour 
{
    #region Singleton
    private static BlackBoard instance = null;
    public static BlackBoard Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new BlackBoard();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    [SerializeField] List<Transform> NavigationPoints = new List<Transform>();
    public List<Transform> Get_NavigationPoints() => NavigationPoints;
    public void Set_NavigationPoints(List<Transform> T) => NavigationPoints = T;
}
```

**NPC_Movement class**

```
public class NPC_Movement
{

    Vector3 direction;

    List<Transform> _navigationPoints = null;
    [SerializeField] public List<Transform> NavigationPoints;
    {
        get
        {
            if (_navigationPoints == null)
            {
                _navigationPoints = BlackBoard.Get_NavigationPoints();
            }
            return _navigationPoints;
        }
    }
    BlackBoard BlackBoard = BlackBoard.Instance;
    

    public void Move()
    {
        // A complex movement function which uses NavigationPoints
    }
}
```

**NPC class**

```
public abstract class NPC : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] protected NPC_Movement Movement;
}
```

**NPC_Guard class**

```
public class NPC_Guard : NPC
{
    void Update()
    {
        Movement.Move();
    }
}
```

**Problem**

> NPC_Movement class does not get the NavigationPoints List .

What am i doing wrong

please help

Comment: It is "not allowed" to use `new` for `MonoBehaviour` derived types ... Also since your NPC Movement seems to be serialized it is initialized right away so you should be careful initializing that field on editor time (on field declaration time)

Comment: What exactly does `does not get the NavigationPoints List .` mean? To me it seems like you might be accessing a different instance of `Blackboard` ...